# Construir una consulta de mysql agrupada

Tags: php, mysql

estoy tratando de montar una consulta pero la verdad no doy pie con bola y no he podido lograrlo.

El tema es este, tengo una bd donde tengo mes el cual identificó como m_mes, tengo otra que se llama actividad la cual llamo m_act y tengo otra que es cantidad la cual identificó como Total.

En el mes yo puedo hacer las siguientes actividades por ejemplo, JUGAR, CANTAR, APLAUDIR, CORRER, SALTAR

Ahora bien, lo que yo quiero hacer, es que la consulta me cuente la cantidad de actividades que yo hago por mes, por ejemplo quiero saber cuantas veces corri, salte y jugue y me las agrupe por mes.

La respuesta debería ser algo asi: Febrero: Correr:2, Saltar:5, Jugar:3,

Hasta ahora he intentado con esta consulta pero no logro que me traiga los resultados que espero.

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) Total FROM metas HAVING COUNT(*) >=1 GROUP BY m_mes
```

La verdad que no tengo idea como hacer para que me raiga los datos que espero, gracias de antemano por su ayuda

Comment: ¿Podrias [edit] tu pregunta, agregar la definición de la tablas y un [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no estás poniendo las campos que estás agrupando. Debes poner el m_mes

```
SELECT m_mes, COUNT(*) Total 
FROM metas  
GROUP BY m_mes  
HAVING COUNT(*) >=1
```